# Calling an External Function in a React Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a need, in a site I'm building, for a list component that is reused several times. However, the list is purely for rendering and is not responsible for the state of the app at all. I know you either cannot, or are not supposed to have dumb components containing any logic, but I am not sure how to proceed without using a smart component, which is entirely unnecessary. Here is my smart component that works:

```
class Menu extends Component {
    renderItems(items) {
        return this.props.items.map((i, index) => {
             return (
                 <li key={index} style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
                    {i}
                </li>
            )
        });
    }
    render() {
        const { listStyle } = styles;
        return (
            <div>
                <ul style={listStyle}>
                    {this.renderItems()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And I've tried this:

```
function Menu(props) {
    return props.items.map((i, index) => {
             <li key={index} style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
                {i}
            </li>
    });
}
```

And then calling it inside Nav like this, which does not throw an error but does not render anything from menu either:

```
const Nav = () => {
    const { listStyle, containerStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <div style={containerStyle}>
            <Logo url={'#'}
                    src={PickAPlayLogo}
                    width={300} />
            <Menu items={pageLinks} />
            <Menu items={socialMediaLinks} />
            <Logo url={'#'}
                    src={AppStoreLogo}
                    width={170} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Also, worth noting, I have never come across a function that is supposed to be rendered like a component, but was trying it based on the example on [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: it should throw an error, try wrapping the Menu function body inside `ul`, like this: `function Menu(Props){return <ul> {  /*map logic*/ } </ul>}`, btw this kind of functions are known as "Stateless Functional Component". Check [**DOC**](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) for more details.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with mapping? I tried this and still nothing renders and there's no error: function Menu(props) {
    return <ul>
            {props.items.map((i, index) => {
                <li key={index}>
                    {i}
                </li>
            })}
         </ul>
}

Comment: ohh really missed that part, you forgot to return inside map body, use `return <li>....</li>` or replace `{}` by `()` here: `return props.items.map((i, index) => (<li>....</li>);` Because you used block body of map so return will be required inside map body.

Answer (score 1):

Heres an answer similar to what you have going on

```
function Menu(props) {
    this.renderItems = () => {
        return (
            <ul>
                {props.items.map((i, index) => {
                   return (
                       <li>{i}</li>
                   )
                })}
            </ul
        )
    }

    return(
        this.renderItems()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
function Menu(props) {
    const {listStyle} = styles;
    const listItems = props.items.map((i, index) =>
                <li key={index} style={{marginLeft: 10}}>
                    {i}
                </li>
        );
    return (
        <ul style={listStyle}>{listItems}</ul>
    );
}
```